# what's the meaning of "!" in 7.2.14 Abstract Equality Comparison of ecmascript spec

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i'm confused a bit that in the Abstract Equality Comparison Section as below:

The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:

1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
   Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == **! ToNumber(y)**.
5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison **! ToNumber(x)** == y.
6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison **! ToNumber(x)** == y.
7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == **! ToNumber(y)**.
8. ...

what is the meaning of '!' for **! ToNumber(x)** and **! ToNumber(y)**?

is anyone can help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is defined in section [5.2.3.4 ReturnIfAbrupt Shorthands](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands)

> Similarly, prefix `!` is used to indicate that the following invocation of an abstract or syntax-directed operation will never return an [abrupt completion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) and that the resulting [Completion Record's](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) `[[Value]]` field should be used in place of the return value of the operation. For example, the step:
>
> ```
> 1. Let val be ! OperationName().
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Let val be OperationName().
> 2. Assert: val is never an abrupt completion.
> 3. If val is a Completion Record, set val to val.[[Value]].
> ```

Abrupt completion records are used to propagate errors, so basically this means that these procedures won't throw an error and that the completion record should be "unwraped" to use the actual value it encapsulates.

Comment: Thanks for you replay,really appreciate it